# App has too many tabs opened in the task-bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm making a WinForm app in C# (Visual studio) for fun. I came across a low-priority problem. It doesn't affect how the app works. But...

On the starting page, I have a button to open a Form1, inside Form1, there's a button to open a Form2 and so on.

At runtime, when I open a form, its parent form does not close and every form is a separate tab in the task-bar. As the layers grow, I'll have more-than-acceptable amount of tabs down there...

Is there a way to have only 1 tab?

I've tried:

1. Adding a parentForm.close() line when opening the form, but that was bad.
2. Instead of creating another form, putting everything in a panel, and bringing out another panel using code, but if there are too many layers, the code gets ridiculously long.

There has to be a simpler way right? Please shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a property in every form called `ShowInTaskbar` which is `true` by default. You can change that in the **form properties** under *Window Style* section or changing it by code manually:

```
Form2.ShowInTaskbar = false;
Form2.ShowDialog();
```

Configure to `false` all forms but the first one in order to achieve your desired behaviour.

Make sure your opened forms are dialogs or you are put them on top so user can never get in the situation where the form is behind and they cannot close it.

Anyway, with a **proper form parenting configuration** (if it fits your needs) you won't need this, as children forms won't appear in the taskbar.

> If a form is parented within another form, the parented form is not displayed in the Windows taskbar.

Make sure you check the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar?view=netframework-4.8) about this.

Comment: awesome! Thanks for the info!